# How can I report number of rows returned from the jdbc sampler?

Tags: jmeter

Is it any way I can report (in the .jtl file) number of rows returned from a call to the jdbc sampler instead of the standard BYTES? This as BYTES reported seems to include rows + headers so a query returning no rows still have bytes reported in that column. I'm trying to separate latency for queries returning rows vs not returning rows.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is configure your JDBC Request sampler to store results into a variable:

[image]

as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)

> If the Variable Names list is provided, then for each row returned by a Select statement, the variables are set up with the value of the corresponding column (if a variable name is provided), and the count of rows is also set up. For example, if the Select statement returns 2 rows of 3 columns, and the variable list is `A,,C`, then the following variables will be set up:
>
> ```
> A_#=2 (number of rows)
> A_1=column 1, row 1
> A_2=column 1, row 2
> C_#=2 (number of rows)
> C_1=column 3, row 1
> C_2=column 3, row 2
> ```

So each JDBC Request sampler will generate `foo_#` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding the number of rows returned by the query.

If you add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
sample_variables=foo_#
```

next time you run your test your .jtl results file will contain an extra column with the respective value of `${foo_#}` variable for each JDBC Request sampler, this way you will be able to tell how many rows were returned for this or that query and what is the relationship between latency and the number of returned rows.

More information:

- [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)